# unable to connect to system bus: failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, vps

I started to use a new VPS system with ubuntu 12.04

After following the commands [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1977769) I installed php, mysql, apache2

PHP and apache are working great but when I run :

```
service mysql start
```

I get : `unable to connect to system bus: failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory.`

I googled but didn't find enough to help me.

*There is no /var/run/dbus/ directory and I don't know what I need to create one or even if this is the problem for mysql.*

Answer (score 18):

I had this error message and discovered that it was a sign that `initctl` (the '[init daemon control tool](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/initctl.8.html)') was being called (indirectly) without the necessary privileges.

In other words:

It failed because:

- I was not logged in as the `root` user,
- nor was I prefixing my 'daemon control' command with `sudo`.

Either one would have solved the issue.

It's a bit confusing because you would have thought a 'privilage issue' would trigger an error message that talks about 'privilage thangs'. But, no. It talks about being "unable to connect to system bus".

**So, may I suggest:**

Try temporarily elevating your privileges by prefixing your command with `sudo`.

Assuming that the hash symbol (`#`) indicates your command prompt, run the following command instead:

```
# sudo service mysql start
```

Then, type in your user password as prompted.

**OR**

If you have set a password for the `root` user on your installation of Ubuntu, you could elevate to that Super User by typing:

```
# su
```

Then, type in the `root` password as prompted.

Then, in **this context**, your original command should, now, work:

```
# service mysql start
```

---

See it's [man page DESCRIPTION](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/initctl.8.html) for more information about `initctl`'s connection to service `start`, `stop`, `restart`, `reload` and `status` commands.